# Is there a platform agnostic implementation of time.gmtime?

Tags: python

on google appengine (http://shell.appspot.com/):

```
>>> time.gmtime(1000*365*24*60*60)
(2969, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 123, 0)
```

on macosx:

```
>>> time.gmtime(1000*365*24*60*60)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

is there a platform agnostic implementation of time.gmtime?

Comment: What version of python do you use on Mac OS X? BTW: no exception thrown on Python 3.1.1 Win32.

Comment: @_jeremy, you'd be better off describing the problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for a fix for the particular approach you have stuck in your mind as a way of solving it.  What do you want to do with this data?

Answer (score 1):

The [time module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) is defined to be platform-specific.

> The functions in this module do not handle dates and times before the epoch or far in the future. The cut-off point in the future is determined by the C library; for Unix, it is typically in 2038.

You can use the [datetime type](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) without timezone info ("naive datetimes"), understood by convention in your program to be GMT, or follow the (complicated) tzinfo instructions in the docs.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2969, 5, 3).year
2969
>>> datetime.MINYEAR, datetime.MAXYEAR
(1, 9999)
```